# rescue how to raise further or forget an exception

Tags: exception, eiffel, design-by-contract

How do I raise an [exception further](https://www.eiffel.org/doc/eiffel/ET-_Design_by_Contract_%28tm%29%2C_Assertions_and_Exceptions#Exception_handling) in eiffel? I have 3 cases

1. I want to **retry**

   ```
   a_feature
       local
           l_retries_count: INTEGER
       do
           some_potential_failing_feature
       rescue
           if l_retries_count <= 3 then
               l_retries_count := l_retries_count + 1
               retry
           end
       end
   ```
2. I want to do **close db connection and ignore exception**

   ```
   a_feature
       do
           some_potential_failing_feature
       rescue
           db_connection.close
       end
   ```
3. I want to do **close db connection and send an email** to an admin and ignore

   ```
   a_feature
       do
           some_potential_failing_feature
       rescue
           db_connection.close
           send_email_to_admin
       end
   ```
4. I want to **close db_connection and raise the exception further**, I'll put all the cases I can think about into the above code

   ```
   a_feature
       local
           l_retries_count: INTEGER
       do
           some_potential_failing_feature
       rescue
           if l_retries_count <= 3 then
               l_retries_count := l_retries_count + 1
               log_error ("Error, retrying for " + l_retries_count.out + "th time")
               retry
           else
               db_connection.close
               send_email_to_admin
               -- raise the_created_exception_from_some_potential_failing_feature -- how do I do that?
           end
       end
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try one of the following:

```
{EXCEPTION_MANAGER}.last_exception.original.raise
{EXCEPTION_MANAGER}.last_exception.cause.raise
{EXCEPTION_MANAGER}.last_exception.raise
```

The first one goes through the chain of exceptions ignoring those triggered as a result of failed routines. It might be the one you are looking for.

The next two retrieve either the cause of the current exception or the current exception itself, though it might be not the one you are looking for because it depends on the context of the exception and the nested calls.